# Upload files to Sharepoint using Powershell and FSRM

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to upload a bunch of files to a SharePoint server. But I want to set the file-metadata before uploading so that it matches with SharePoint property and buckets it. **Need help in setting file-metadata by powershell/FSRM FCI**
SharePoint property is day, month, year.
The SharePoint application is not installed on my system. So i don't have any access to the cmdlets/SharePoint management console.
The source can be from local system win7 sp1/ remote system win 08 R2.

Currently using :

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $file.Name, "PUT", $file.FullName)
```

Update from OP:

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment. But I don't think I explained my problem clearly.

Excel files contain a start-date and end-date column inside it.
In order for my sharepoint server to group by Month and Year I need to ensure these properties are populated programmatically prior to upload.

I have achieved upload via calling powershell script on FSRM. e.g. Script1.ps1.

My approach: I defined a property 'Year' in classification properties and realised I will need a powershell classification rule. Saying if end-date > current_date then populate year(current_date) else year(end_date).Same with 'Month'. How to do this in powershell? Once this is done I will schedule both tasks one after the other. Thanks.

Comment: By metadata you mean the properties of the file? I doubt we can set before we upload a file in the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a console application and write CSOM code like below:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
     using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
     {
         var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
         var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
         clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

         Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);
     }
}
```

**SaveBinaryDirect** is quite a powerful function.

Answer (score -1):

```
Here’s a quick example of how to upload a document on a SharePoint server using the SharePoint PowerShell module which uses the SharePoint Object Model.

# Set the variables 
$WebURL = “http://Siteurl/sites/stuff” 
$DocLibName = “Docs” 
$FilePath = “C:\Docs\stuff\Secret Sauce.docx” 

# Get a variable that points to the folder 
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL 
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName) 
$Files = $List.Files

# Get just the name of the file from the whole path 
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1)

# Load the file into a variable 
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

# Upload it to SharePoint 
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false) 
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: For more information see this below link. [Upload a file](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=487)

Comment: This is server side code, the question is how to upload files with metadata from a machine outside the SharePoint farm (which would require CSOM code)